# Copy data between two tables in PostgreSQL using dblink.sql

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-9.1, dblink

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1. I need to transfer required columns from one table of one database into another table of another database, but not schema.
I found that `dblink.sql` file has to be there in `share/contrib`. But my `contrib` folder is empty. Where can I download the `dblink.sql` file and can execute my query?

When I execute the query now it shows an error message:

```
cross database reference is not possible ...
```

Can anyone help me how to transfer the data between two databases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use (install) dblink in postgresql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862648/how-to-use-install-dblink-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 8):

After you have installed the package into your system [as detailed in the related  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862648/how-to-use-install-dblink-in-postgresql) install the [extension `dblink`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html) into your database (the one you are running this code in, the foreign db does not need it):

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

You can find [code examples in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html).
Here is a simple version of what I use to copy data between dbs:
First, [create a FOREIGN SERVER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createserver.html)

```
CREATE SERVER mydb
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgresql
OPTIONS (hostaddr '111.111.111.111',port '5432',dbname 'mydb');
```

`FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgresql` was pre-installed in my case.
Then create function that opens a connection, removes old data (opotional), fetches new data, runs `ANALYZE` and closes the connection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tbl_sync()
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
SELECT dblink_connect('mydb');  -- USER MAPPING for postgres, PW in .pgpass

TRUNCATE tbl;  -- optional

INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT * FROM dblink(
  'SELECT tbl_id, x, y
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY tbl_id')
    AS b(
 tbl_id int
,x int
,y int)

ANALYZE tbl;

SELECT dblink_disconnect();
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```