# How can I copy/transfer/restore a table (Not entire database ) from one PostgreSQL to another through Heroku CLI?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

I'm looking possible way to copy some tables of one PostgreSQL DB to another DB. With PGAdmin, backup and restore is really confusing and mess. Is there a way to backup and restore specific tables via Heroku CLI? Or some other ways?

Comment: `pg_dump -t the_table ...` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3049864/330315) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1237725/330315)